# Leak while decrementing a date in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsdate

I'm having some troubles fixing a leak detected by Instruments. I'm trying to decrement a date in a loop, using the `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` method of `NSCalendar`, and I keep having leaks of `NSDate` objects (49 to be exact).

Here is what my code looks like:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
// Get current date
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
// Create an NSDateComponents object that will be used to decrement the date
NSDateComponents *decStep = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[decStep setDay:-1];

for (NSUInteger i = 49; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    // Insert the date object in an array
    [self.fooArray insertObject:date atIndex:0];
    // Decrement the date
    date = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:decStep toDate:date options:0];
}

// Release calendar and date components objects
[decStep release];
[gregorian release];
```

I've tried to fix this leak by few different ways, but as I don't understand why it leaks in the first place, I really have no idea of what I'm doing. Do you have any clues that would help me fix this issue, knowing that I would prefer not to use `NSAutoreleasePool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you are leaking?  If it's just Instruments reporting that you've now got 50 more date objects, then that's true.  They'll be kept around until you set self.fooArray to something else, at which point (if you use the setter), they'll be released.

Comment: Well, you were both right! The leak wasn't coming from the date, but from the array. `self.fooArray` was declared retain instead of copy, and after changing it to copy, I had to use a temporary array and release it after doing `self.fooArray = tpmArray`. Thanks!

Comment: I think the facts that I was using the factory method `date` of `NSDate`, and that I was reusing the variable `date`, had me look in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I see no memory leak. You get 50 dates in the `fooArray`, that's 50 objects retained by the array. That's not a leak.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are adding the dates into an array.
2. I believe `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options` creates a new date object and calls autorelease on it. You need an NSAutoReleasePool to get rid of those instances.